# Selectively exclude a property on one JSON serialization but not on another

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.text.json, .net-7.0

I have a POCO like this

```cs
public class Foo {
   public string PartitionKey => $"foo-{Bar}";
   public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I'm storing that POCO as serialized JSON in a database (Azure Cosmos DB to be specific) and making it available to clients via a ASP.NET WebApi.

When serializing that document for Cosmos DB, I need the PartitionKey, so I cannot exclude it totally by using `[JsonIgnore]`. But I do not want it included in my API response. So what is the easiest way to achieve this? Ideally I don't want to write my own JsonSerializer, but maybe using some custom attribute?

Expected outcomes:

For the database:

```json
{
  "partitionKey": "foo-alice",
  "bar": "alice"
}
```

For the api response:

```json
{
  "bar": "alice"
}
```

Using .NET7 and `System.Text.Json`

Comment: I have an approach in mind, but with a custom JsonConverter and that you are not looking for, right?

Comment: Personally I would just create a DTO and map the entity to it.

Comment: @GuruStron yeah I thought about it, too. But except for that one property they would look exactly the same (and there are plenty of more properties which I left out here)

Comment: @viveknuna if possible I'd like to avoid that. But feel free to post it if nobody has a better idea

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. Pls post json that you have now for API response, and json you want to send as API response. I don't understand what the difference it should be to cause such a problem

Comment: @Serge I think it was clear before, but I added examples of the outcomes now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple options to selectively exclude the `PartitionKey` property during serialization.

**Firstly**, since the property is read-only, you could set [`JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.ignorereadonlyproperties):

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true,
    // Add other options as required
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase, 
    WriteIndented = true,           
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(foo, options);
```

This will exclude **all** read-only properties including `PartitionKey`.

**Secondly**, if you need to exclude only `PartitionKey` but include other read-only properties, or exclude modifiable properties, or otherwise need more control over what gets serialized, you can add a [DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts#modifiers) to exclude the unwanted members.

To exclude the property by name, add the following extension method:

```
public static partial class JsonSerializerExtensions
{
    public static DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver Exclude(this DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver resolver, Type type, params string [] membersToExclude)
    {
        if (resolver == null || membersToExclude == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var membersToExcludeSet = membersToExclude.ToHashSet();
        resolver.Modifiers.Add(typeInfo => 
                               {
                                   if (typeInfo.Kind == JsonTypeInfoKind.Object && type.IsAssignableFrom(typeInfo.Type)) // Or type == typeInfo.Type if you don't want to exclude from subtypes
                                       foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
                                           if (property.GetMemberName() is {} name && membersToExcludeSet.Contains(name))
                                               property.ShouldSerialize = static (obj, value) => false;
                               });
        return resolver;
    }

    public static string? GetMemberName(this JsonPropertyInfo property) => (property.AttributeProvider as MemberInfo)?.Name;
}
```

And now you will be able to do:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver()
        .Exclude(typeof(Foo), nameof(Foo.PartitionKey)),
    // Add other options as required
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase, 
    WriteIndented = true,           
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(foo, options);
```

If you want to exclude by custom attribute rather than by name, introduce the following extension method:

```
public static partial class JsonSerializerExtensions
{
    public static DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver ExcludeByAttribute<TAttribute>(this DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver resolver) where TAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
        if (resolver == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var attr = typeof(TAttribute);
        resolver.Modifiers.Add(typeInfo => 
                               {
                                   if (typeInfo.Kind == JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
                                       foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
                                           if (property.AttributeProvider?.IsDefined(attr, true) == true)
                                               property.ShouldSerialize = static (obj, value) => false;
                               });
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Then modify `Foo` as follows:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class JsonExludeFromResponseAttribute : System.Attribute { }

public class Foo {
    [JsonExludeFromResponseAttribute]
    public string PartitionKey => $"foo-{Bar}";
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And exclude `PartitionKey` as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver()
        .ExcludeByAttribute<JsonExludeFromResponseAttribute>(),
    // Add other options as required
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase, 
    WriteIndented = true,           
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(foo, options);
```

Notes:

- Contract customization is [new in .NET 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#contract-customization).
- If you have many different types with a `PartitionKey` property which you always want to exclude, you could pass in `typeof(object)` as the base class from which to exclude the property.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IAhicu).

Comment: thanks! I'll probably go the way of the custom attribute