# Serialize props marked JsonIgnore

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I know that this solution is a hack. But so far, I haven't come up with anything better for my needs.

There is a class:

```c#
public class Request 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I need to ignore the "Age" property during deserialization, but I need it during serialization.

So far, I have only come up with using two serializers: System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft, and leaving the [JsonIgnore] attribute for the System.Text.Json serializer only. When I need to include the "Age" field, I will use Newtonsoft.

But I feel that this is very hacky, and I don't like this plan.

Why I'm resorting to a hack:

> Why am I even resorting to a hack: At one point, I make a request to an external system. The external system returns the same results for identical requests (if it matters, it's a service for building routes from point A to point B, disregarding traffic). I don't want to burden the external system with unnecessary requests.
> So, I've decided to cache the requests. The problem is that the "request" is an object (in this example, it's a type of Request) that comes to me in the controller. In other words, it's a new object every time, even if the contents of the request are the same.
> Therefore, I decided to use a serialized string as the cache key.
> There are three alternatives that came to mind.
> 1. Records. I'm not sure if the cache will use full comparison instead of reference comparison. But it's worth testing and not dismissing this option.
> 2. Caching md5. Honestly, I'm scared of collisions here. If they occur (and everything bad should happen sooner or later), then I'll be debugging the code for a long time and not understanding why I'm getting the wrong route. A partial solution would be to use more complex hashing algorithms, but then the question of performance becomes even more acute.
> 3. (As I was writing this question, I realized that I like this option even more than using two serializers). Cache the combination of the URL and body of the request that I want to send to the external service.

Comment: You may use a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) to "unignore" properties marked with `[JsonIgnore]`.  See [Can I optionally turn off the JsonIgnore attribute at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37371786).  See also [Serialize Property, but Do Not Deserialize Property in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31731320).  In fact your question looks to be a duplicate of one of those, agree?

Comment: Or do you prefer to use System.Text.Json instead of Json.NET?  Which `[JsonIgnore]` are you applying?  If `[JsonIgnore]` is from System.Text.Json then those two questions do not apply and I should not have closed this as a duplicate, and will reopen.

Comment: For the System.Text.Json equivalent of configuring a contract resolver to selectively ignore properties, see [Selectively exclude a property on one JSON serialization but not on another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74928838/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

your question doesn't make any sense for me at all. But this code works for "I need to ignore the "Age" property during deserialization, but I need it during serialization."

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    var request = new Request { Name = "John", Age = 90 };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

    request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(json);

public class Request
{
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConstructor]
    public Request(int Age) {}
    
    public Request() { }
}
```